# Hibernate JPA @OneToMany join on 2 columns with OR statement in Entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have the following class:

```
public class Nomenclature extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NOMENCLATURE_CODE")
    private String nomenclatureCode;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "nomenclatureCode",     orphanRemoval = true)
     private List<Cumul> cumuls = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I want to join the following Cumul class on 2 columns WHERE cumul.nomenclatureCode = nomenclature.nomenclatureCode OR cumul.nomenclatureCodeAllowedCumul = nomenclature.nomenclatureCode

```
public class Cumul extends BaseEntity  {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "NUMERIC")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "CUMUL", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;


    @Column(name = "NOMENCLATURE_CODE")
    private String nomenclatureCode;

    @Column(name = "NOMENCLATURE_CODE_ALLOWED_CUMUL")
    private String nomenclatureCodeAllowedCumul;
```

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumns(
        {
                @JoinColumn(name = "nomenclature_code", referencedColumnName = "nomenclature_code"),
                @JoinColumn(name = "nomenclature_code_allowed_cumul", referencedColumnName = "nomenclature_code")
        })
private List<Cumul> cumuls = new ArrayList<>();
```

Worked but this an AND statement not an OR what I was looking for

Comment: JPA entities and mappings are two way; readable and writeable. This won't work as there is no way to write out this 'cumulus' relationship when you add a new Cumul to it. And JPA requires foreign keys point at primary keys in the entities they reference - this ensures object identity and caching is maintained - while JPA providers support using non-id fields, they generally are inefficient and have to hit the database. While I"m sure you can get something close to what you want - do you really need this in your model itself? Make the query yourself and avoid costs

Comment: I need this in the model itself. The reason is somewhere else in the code I save the Nomenclature Entity. So when it is saved the relationship should be linked right in the Entity